# magento admin dropdown issue

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I set a default value in a magento admin dropdown?

Here's my system.xml

```
<related_items_to_display translate="label" module="ddg">
                            <label>Items To Display</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>automation/adminhtml_source_dynamic_gridview</source_model>
                            <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </related_items_to_display>
```

And I've got my source model here:

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    return array(
        array('value' => '2', 'label' => '2'),
        array('value' => '4', 'label' => '4'),
        array('value' => '6', 'label' => '6'),
        array('value' => '8', 'label' => '8'),
    );

}
```

Is there a way to set default value to 8? Without changing the order of this array?

Comment: Can you please share your Source model file path ??

Comment: Basically this is what I've tried: <default>
         <connector_dynamic_content>
             <products>
                   <related_items_to_display>4</related_items_to_display>
             </products>
         </connector_dynamic_content>
    </default> but it did not have any effect

Comment: just i need source file class name so i verify with <source_model>automation/adminhtml_source_dynamic_gridview</source_model> that code which you enter in system.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the default values from the `config.xml` file like below :

```
<default>
    <mysection>
        <mygroup>                
            <myfield>My Default Value</myfield>         
        </mygroup>      
    </mysection>
</default>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw this exact code on stack, but I couldn't figure out how it goes with my block of code ..:/?

Comment: paste the entire code of your  `system.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value in config.xml for this configuration

```
<default>
 <section_name>
   <group_name>
      <related_items_to_display>8</related_items_to_display>
   </group_name>
 </section_name>
</default>
```